# how to create pre-designed ( Template ) form in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, desktop-application

I have a multi-form C# application, and most of this forms have the same design like (custom borders , custom control box ...) and they programmed.
So my question, how can I create a template form instead of copying the design and code? Or in other words, how to make all forms inherit the design and programming from the main form?

I expected that I could program and design one form and have others inherit the same design and programming.

Comment: You can derive a Form from a base Form or save a Form as a Template that you can then find among the other Templates in the standard dialog (`Project->Export Template->Item Template`)

Comment: i find a solution thank you , Right click on your solution > add > new item > windows form > inherited form > select the form you want to inherit from it.

Comment: I decided to leave the question without deleting it so that others can benefi

Comment: Don't confuse templating and inheritance.

Comment: That's only available in .NET Framework. Maybe you want to test the other methods for when you decide to migrate to .NET 6+

Comment: Dive into WPF and styles, and let Windows Forms get retired)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your solution > add > new item > windows form > inherited form > select the form you want to inherit from it.

Comment: Please note that you should not include meta information (historical notes, greetings, thanks, unrelated comments, etc) into posts (both questions and answers). Also this answer does not answer the question as-asked. Since you are OP of the question and there are no other answers you may as well adjust the question to matche the answer (probably de-emphasizing "template" from the question in favor of "need all form to share design basics" requirements).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).